# How can I reply to a tweet and show that to my followers?

Tags: twitter, retweet

How should I comment on someone else's tweet to make my comment visible to the original tweeter and other users looking at the original tweet replies **and** my own followers?

I've noticed that if I "retweet with comment" someone's tweet then my followers will see it, but it doesn't show up in the original tweet as a reply, and I don't think it shows up as a retweet.

If I reply to a tweet then it is only shown on the timeline of users that follow both me and the original tweeter.

If I link to the tweet then it is taken out of the original twitter thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can retweet your own posts and replies. If you want to both reply to a thread so that your reply stays within the thread and make sure that your reply shows up on your followers' timelines, you can retweet your own reply after you've posted it so that it shows up.

So step 1: Write your reply. Step 2: Retweet your own reply. Step 3: Have it show up in your followers' timelines (although it will show up as "X retweeted...."). (Step 4: ??? Step 5: Profit.)

As an aside, your regular replies *will* show up sometimes naturally in their timelines. The algorithm works in mysterious ways, but I will see replies sometimes from people I follow when sorting my Twitter feed by "latest" instead of "top Tweets".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reply to a tweet and at the same time have that reply-tweet appear as public tweet. The most common work-around is as follows:

1. Click the  **`retweet`** button and select **`Retweet with comment`** (on mobile) or use the **`Add a comment...`** field (on desktop).
2. Begin your tweet with **`.@username`**, after it type in your reply. Make sure to put a dot **`.`** before the **`@username`** otherwise your tweet will be processed as a reply:

[image]

3. The result of this method will be a **public tweet** where the **`@username`** you are replying to is @mentioned right at the top, followed by your reply, while the tweet you are replying to is quoted at the bottom:

[image]

4. Last, copy the URL of the reply tweet and paste it in a new public tweet with a bit of context. That would be your public tweet (with the reply) available to all your followers.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that doesn't show up as a RT for the tweet, nor appear threaded under the original tweet.

Comment: In that case, what you can do is first reply to the tweet you wish to reply to and then copy the URL of the reply tweet and paste it in a new public tweet with a bit of context

Comment: I guess I could retweet my answer instead? What's the difference? Anyway, I think this is the best solution if you want to add that to your answer?

Comment: edited the answer...